# Add a custom button to CKEditor

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, ckeditor

Hi I want to add a custom button for CKEditor in drupal. I created a plugin, but it is not displaying in my ckeditor toolbar. Can some one help me? The code is as follows

plugin.js

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('newplugin',
{
    init: function(editor)
    {
        var pluginName = 'newplugin';
        CKEDITOR.dialog.add(pluginName, this.path + 'plugin.js');
        editor.addCommand(pluginName, new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand(pluginName));
        editor.ui.addButton('Newplugin',
            {
                label: 'Footnote or Citation',
        icon: this.path + 'newplugin.png',
                command: pluginName
            });
    }
});

config.js
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{


config.extraPlugins = 'newplugin';
config.toolbar = [
['Bold'],['Italic'],['newplugin']
]
};
```

Comment: Drupal uses... CKEditor? **edit:** ah... YUI Rich Editor

Comment: Thanks for the response . Yeah it used CKEditor

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the WYSIWYG module? If so, you have to create a module that implements the wysiwyg hook to add the button to the configuration. This can be done using the following code:

```
function yourtheme_wysiwyg_plugin($editor, $version) {
    switch ($editor) {
        return array(
            'PluginName' => array(
                'path' => "Path to plugin directory",
                'filename' => 'plugin.js',
                'buttons' => array(
                    'Newplugin' => t('New Plugin'),
                ),
                'load' => TRUE,
                'internal' => FALSE,
            ),
        );
        break;
    }
}
```

Then upload the theme to Drupal and clear your caches. The button should now appear in the list of buttons on the WYSIWYG administration page where you can select the checkbox and enable the button.